# assign variable to the selected option value of a form

Tags: javascript

I have a simple drop-down menu that lists various monthly dates for November 1954 to January 2014 - this is my options array - options.js. When the user selects a month I want to retrieve the option value which is the index number of this array. For example if the user selects October 1966 - this "value" would be 143 - so what I want is to store this value as a number in a variable.

TIA

here is my code:

```
<script src="options.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function startdate() {
    var select = document.getElementById('StartDate');
    var i;
            for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            var opt = options[i];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = i;
            select.appendChild(el);
            }
}
window.onload = startdate;
```

Comment: Thanks zord - much appreciated. BTW I edited the code slightly - my original code seemed to have a problem

Comment: You're welcome. I changed the variable name in my answer to reflect your edit. Let me know if you need anything else to make my answer acceptable.

Comment: Thanks zord - it is working as it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is ok, you just need to bind an event handler to `select.onchange`:

```
var currentStartDate = 0;
```

...

```
select.onchange = function () { 
    currentStartDate = select.value;
    alert("value: " + currentStartDate); 
}
```

Here is a [demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ppaj9/).